# GroupBy + Condition

Tags: google-bigquery, sql

If I have a table like

```
ID | Start  | End    | Name | Code
1  | 1000   | 1001   | ABC1 |  A
1  | 1000   | 1001   | FSD1 |  B
2  | 1200   | 1201   | CC12 |  A
3  | 4000   | 4002   | GF41 |  B
3  | 4000   | 4002   | ML65 |  A
```

Using SQL Standard, can we write the following if condition:

if for (ID, Start, End), code is A and B, then only prints the 
record w/ B. Otherwise, print the record. Here is the output:

```
ID | Start  | End    | Name | Code
1  | 1000   | 1001   | FSD1 |  B
2  | 1200   | 1201   | CC12 |  A
3  | 4000   | 4002   | GF41 |  B
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table`  AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1000 start, 1001 `end`, 'ABC1' name, 'A' code UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1000, 1001, 'FSD1', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1200, 1201, 'CC12', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4000, 4002, 'GF41', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4000, 4002, 'ML65', 'A' 
)
SELECT 
  id, start, `end`, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, code) ORDER BY code DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`
GROUP BY id, start, `end` 
-- ORDER BY id
```

result should be

```sql
Row id  start   end     name    code     
1   1   1000    1001    FSD1    B    
2   2   1200    1201    CC12    A    
3   3   4000    4002    GF41    B
```

Alternative option with same result, but can be useful if you have more/other fields in your table that you need to include into output

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table`  AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 1000 start, 1001 `end`, 'ABC1' name, 'A' code UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1000, 1001, 'FSD1', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1200, 1201, 'CC12', 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4000, 4002, 'GF41', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 4000, 4002, 'ML65', 'A' 
)
SELECT row.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY code DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] row
  FROM `project.dataset.your_table` t
  GROUP BY id, start, `end` 
)
-- ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by code desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The advantage of this approach over an aggregation approach is that it readily includes all the columns, without the overhead of aggregation.

Comment: also you can add EXCEPT(seqnum) to eliminate that intermediate field from final output